# Magento 2 - How to filter products collection by category url key

Tags: php, magento2

I try to filter a product collection by know category urlKey on Magento 2.0 EE.

Now I've got:

```
        /** @var $collection \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection */
        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();

        $collection->setVisibility($this->_catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter();
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your entire problem? Any error messages?

Comment: No error message.
My code get All Products. I just need to filter this collection by category urlKey.
I think I need to get the category (how?), and inject it in the $collection->addCategoryFilter(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category) function.